# Extract date, name and activities from a string Google sheet

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, extract

Extract date, name and activity from string

| String | Result 1 | Result 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [21/3/2023 1:20 pm] Murugappan: Murugappan 30 min lunch | 21/3/2023Murugappan | 30minslunch |
| [21:33, 3/04/2023 Palash: No dinner | 3/4/2023Palash | Nodinner |

Formula tried but only row 1 worked, row 2 failed due to the time and date sequence.

```
arrayformula(SUBSTITUTE( iferror(regexextract(unique(if(B2:B<>"",regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexextract(B2:B,",\ (.*)"),"[\]\:]",),"(\d)(min)(s)?(.*)","$1mins $4"),"\ min","min"),"Lunch","lunch"),"Dinner","dinner"),"\ {2,}","\ "),"(0)?(\d\/)","$2"),)),"(.*)\ ([\dN].*)"),)," ","",1))
```

Data file provided,
[Please click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jTEIkZR6gd_WgRM32K9yjGctFTm_hDIZSx2GaodICdU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jTEIkZR6gd_WgRM32K9yjGctFTm_hDIZSx2GaodICdU/edit#gid=370983092):

```
=index(split(tocol(map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,
       ifna(regexextract(Σ,"(\d+/\d+/\d+)\b"))& 
       iferror(split(ifna(regexextract(Σ,": (.*) (?:\d+ |No )"),regexextract(Σ,"\d (.*):")),", "))&"|"&
       ifna(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexextract(Σ,"((?:\d+|No)[^:]*)$"),"\s",),"(min)","$1s"))))),1),"|"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @rockinfreakshow. However, I realize due to human nature there is no way to standardize how everyone enters "mins" in the system. How to tweak the  formula so that it takes away all "s" after the "min" no matter users enter "min" or "mins"

Comment: Updated the formula in the `Sol,` tab. do test it out.

Comment: It a mixed bag of results. Please refer to `Sol,` tab.

Comment: Updated formula added

Comment: The amazing formula worked on so many scenarios. Thank you very much for your help.